# DB2 Sql how to use the case statement?

Tags: sql, db2, case-statement

I am trying to extract all event end dates for events that expire in 2 working days. So for Friday and Thursday I want dates that end in 4 days or less, for Saturday dates that end in 3 days, for Sun-Wed dates that end within 2 days and +3 for all public holidays which are listed in column dateval in tempdate.

The script below isn't working, it only extact dates for +2 days. I understand I need to use a case statement, but am really not understanding how to implement that. Does someone have any ideas?

```
select event_end_date
from mdmins.table

/*separating by date to find expiring dates*/ 
where  (  (dayofweek(c.event_end_date) in (5,6) /*Friday & Thursday*/ 
and    date(c.event_end_date) < current_date + 4 days 
and    date(c.event_end_date) >= current_date) 
or     (dayofweek(c.event_end_date) in (1,2,3,4) /*All other days of week*/ 
and    date(c.event_end_date) < current_date + 2 days 
and    date(c.event_end_date) >= current_date) 
or     (dayofweek(c.event_end_date) = 7 /*Saturday - not that this should be needed, but just in case*/ 
and    date(c.event_end_date) < current_date + 3 days 
and    date(c.event_end_date) >= current_date) 
or     (date(c.event_end_date) < (select dateval from mdmins.tempdate where dateval = (current date + 3 days)) /*a holiday is on in 3 days, so 2 working days before*/ 
and    date(c.event_end_date) >= current_date) )
```

Comment: I though to useing it in this way:  where  (date(event_end_date) between (case when dayofweek(current_date) in (5,6) then (current_date + 4 days) else null end) and (case when dayofweek(current_date) in (5,6) then current_date else null end))
  but not working yet :/

Comment: This isn't a `CASE` statement (which is an actual thing), and you don't need one.  Do you have an outright Calendar file with a `workingDay` Boolean column?  That would make this far easier to write.  Calendar files are, hands down, one of the most useful analysis tables possible.  Barring that, creating a temp/virtual table via CTE and `VALUES(...)` would greatly simplify this.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, the only thing that varies between the data of the week is how far ahead you look, so limit the logic to that using a case:

```
...
where date(c.event_end_date) between current_date and current_date +
  case
    when dayofweek(c.event_end_date) in (5, 6) then 4
    when dayofweek(c.event_end_date) in (1, 2, 3, 4) then 2
    else 3
  end days
or (date(c.event_end_date) < (select dateval
  from mdmins.tempdate
  where dateval = (current date + 3 days)) 
  and date(c.event_end_date) >= current_date)
```

Comment: This is a really good point. I like the way you arranged it! Unfortunately I am getting the same problem as with my original sql, it is only pulling days that are +2 although we are at say 5...so I am only getting things that expiry on the 19th and 20th :/

Comment: Got it!! this will work with the script below. Obviously will need to wait till tomorrow to see if it runs as it should, but for now it's looking good!

where ((date(c.event_end_date) between current_date and current_date +
      case
        when dayofweek(current date) in (5,6) then 4
        when dayofweek(current date) in (1, 2, 3, 4) then 2
        else 3
      end days)
or    date(c.event_end_date) < (select dateval
      from mdmins.tempdate
      where dateval = (current date + 3 days)) 
      and date(c.event_end_date) >= current_date )

Comment: How about holidays?  If you need to take those into account, then the Calendar file @Clockwork-Muse mentions is the way to go.

Comment: Yea we have the dates of all the European public holidays in this dateval column so here we are setting a buffer on those too. I'm sure there is a better way of doing this, but our system is a little messy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
where ((date(c.event_end_date) between current_date and current_date +
  case
    when dayofweek(current date) in (5,6) then 4
    when dayofweek(current date) in (1, 2, 3, 4) then 2
    else 3
  end days)
  or    date(c.event_end_date) < (select dateval
      from mdmins.tempdate
      where dateval = (current date + 3 days)) 
      and date(c.event_end_date) >= current_date )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of why you want a calendar that includes all dates, with a bunch of extra information.  You'd be able to do something similar to this:

```
WITH Desired_Dates AS (SELECT MIN(calendarDate) AS startRange,
                              MAX(calendarDate) + 1 DAY AS endRange
                       FROM(SELECT calendarDate
                            FROM Calendar
                            WHERE calendarDate >= CURRENT_DATE
                                  AND dayOfWeekISO IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                                  AND isHolday = '0'
                            ORDER BY calendarDate
                            FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY) D)
SELECT C.<column_list
FROM <Your_Table> C
JOIN Desired_Dates D
  ON C.event_end_date >= D.startRange
     AND C.event_end_Date < D.endRange
```

(Note that I'm specifically using the ISO day-of-week, where **Monday** is 1.  Sunday as 1 is a US thing, and functions to derive day-of-week from a given date are subject to the whims of the current culture settings.  Also, in the case that `event_end_date` is something like a timestamp, you want to use an exclusive end range
This actually has a decent chance of using index-only information to grab the desired dates (assuming a relevant index) and in any case will only grab the data in the CTE once.

If you don't have a calendar table, you can make one:

```
WITH Working_Dates AS (SELECT CURRENT_DATE - 1 DAY AS calendarDate, 
                              0 AS workingDayNum, '0' AS isWorkingDay
                       FROM SYSIBM/SYSDUMMY1
                       UNION ALL 
                       SELECT calendarDate, 
                              workingDayNum + CASE WHEN isWorkingDay = 1
                                                   THEN 1
                                                   ELSE 0 END AS workingDayNum,
                              isWorkingDay
                       FROM (SELECT calendarDate, workingDayNum,
                                    CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK_ISO(WD.calendarDate) IN (6, 7)
                                              OR Holiday.dateval IS NOT NULL 
                                         THEN '0'
                                         ELSE '1' END AS isWorkingDay
                             FROM (SELECT calendarDate + 1 DAY, workingDayNum
                                   FROM Working_Dates
                                   WHERE workingDayNum < 2) WD
                             LEFT JOIN mdmins.tempdate Holiday
                                    ON Holiday.dateval = WD.calendarDate) WD),

     Desired_Dates AS (SELECT MIN(calendarDate) AS startRange,
                              MAX(calendarDate) + 1 DAY AS endRange
                       FROM Working_Date
                       WHERE isWorkingDay = '1')

SELECT C.<column_list
FROM <Your_Table> C
JOIN Desired_Dates D
  ON C.event_end_date >= D.startRange
     AND C.event_end_Date < D.endRange
```

This is using a recursive CTE to loop through days from (one before) the current date until three working days have passed.  (I had to start it a day early so I only had to write the "is it a working day" logic once, which is also why all the nesting).

Note that neither your original attempts, nor any of the existing answers take these into account:

1. What happens if there's a holiday on a Friday or a Monday (5 days to skip, not 4)?
2. What happens if there are multiple holidays in sequence (unknown number of days to skip)?

By building a list of the actual working days, we can insulate ourselves from the problem.